# When start and end of day times change, remove/add correct <tr>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a created a grid view for organizing sessions of an event. This grid has the times of the day in 30 min increments down the left most column, then to the right different tracks the event has. you can drag and drop session around he grid to schedule your event ect.

There is a modal that allows the user to change the times for that specific day. Currently, I have it setup to refresh the page when a user changes the time, that way the grid updates.

I would like to add or remove the necessary time rows without refreshing the page. Not really sure how to do the math on this one..  I know for sure it possible.

The organizer is behind a PW protected app, but if you guys still don't understand the problem I can try to peice together a fiddle. (would be hard and time consuming to make it run without the server).

Here is my current save day function:

```
 saveEditDay: function(clicked){
        var fm = $('.edit-day-form');
        if(fm.valid()){
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: '<?=URL::to_action("api.day")?>/' + day_buttons.dayId,
                data: fm.serialize(),
                success: function(dayObject){
                    console.log('changing the button');
                    //only "current" day can be edited, so:
                    dayObject.is_current = true;
                    $('#day-btn-'+dayObject.id).replaceWith(ich.day_btn(dayObject));
                    $('.edit_header time').attr('datetime',dayObject.happens_at).text(dayObject.date_long);
                    //console.log(dayObject)
                    $('.days').trigger('change');
                    $('#edit_day_modal').modal('hide');  

                    //day_buttons.removeHourRows(dayObject)

                    //Temporary fix for showing new day times on save.
                    window.location = window.location.pathname;
                }
            });
        }
    },
```

Here is the code for the calendar I am trying to add/remove tr's from:

http://jsfiddle.net/5QFAw/6/

Comment: Please provide some code for what the underlying problem is

Comment: In general, you overlay a DIV over the grid. you don't change the grid itself. See the demo here: http://www.bryntum.com/products/scheduler/

Comment: overlay a div? that doesn't seem like the most effective approach. I am not seeing the example you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

According to further understanding, this might be what you want:

```
$(function () {
    var foo = function (t) {  // t = the input of user
        $(".YourTBodyClass tr").each(function () { // Assign a specific class to your tobody, or if you just want to deal with one table then id will be fine as well

            if ($(this).attr("data-val") < t) { // I assume you can assign a "int" data-val to each tr with 8,9,10....24. 
                                                // Of couse you can also try compare with the data-id you have in your jsfiddle, it's just slightly more complicated.
                                                // If data-val is used, you can use other unobtrusive val

                $(this).css("display", "none"); // I will prefer to just hide the tr rather than wipe, so that you don't need to worry about recreating it

            } else {

                $(this).css("display", "block");

            }
        });
    };
});
```

View comments in js, please let me know if you got any question.

Gook luck again.

Comment: I dont't know how to writei the code I am trying to create. I thought I did a farily good job of explaining the peice of functionality I am looking for. To add or subtract rows fro mthe table base on the users input for the hours of the day. Seems like  Ijust need some thing like(in pseudo code) `if(start_time < $(td:first).data('time')){ add rows to make the first row the new start time}else{subtract rows to make new start time first row.}`Then also the same idea for the end time. I really hope this makes more sense to you :). thank you for the time

Comment: Ok I guess I totally misunderstood what you want. So basically you want to: when user enter "9" into some input and click update, the table will simply wipe out all time before 9:00? And when user enter "8", the page should add the 8:00 and 8:30 back? Am I understanding it right this time?

Comment: Yep, you got it. Sorry if my orignal post was not clear! Can you think of a way to accomplish this?